# Rails 3: How to prevent users to change the database by typing a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to-remote

I have the following link:

```
link_to("Toggle", "/jobs/#{job.id}/toggle_is_money_paid", :remote => true)
```

which toggles the `is_money_paid` field of a job using an Ajax request:

```
def toggle_is_money_paid
  job = Job.find(params[:id])
  job.update_attributes(:is_money_paid => !job.is_money_paid)
  render :nothing => true
end

# config/routes.rb
match "/jobs/:id/toggle_is_money_paid" => "jobs#toggle_is_money_paid"
```

However, if user types directly:

```
http://localhost:3001/jobs/200/toggle_is_money_paid
```

in the browser, it will toggle the `is_money_paid` field of job #200.

How could I prevent this, such that users could toggle the field only by pressing the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prevent this by not defining the route using `match`, but instead by using one of the HTTP verbs that isn't get. More than likely, you'll want to use `put`:

```
put "/jobs/:id/toggle_is_money_paid" => "jobs#toggle_is_money_paid"
```

Then you'll change your `link_to` to this:

```
link_to("Toggle", "/jobs/#{job.id}/toggle_is_money_paid", :remote => true, :method => :put)
```

Comment: What? This is not a solution. The only thing it's doing is making the request harder to do, but still possible.

Comment: @ryeguy It prevents CSRF so only the user himself can toggle the field.

Comment: @ryeguy: People cannot type the URL into the address bar and have it work. The method needs to be PUT, but URLs are GET.

Comment: @ryeguy: Secondly, I'd like you to take away that downvote you've put there, unless you've got a solid reason why this isn't a solution.